# Regex match only all given characters with duplicates

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with one regex pattern problem and I didn't find any similar thread.

For example, I have following characters:

`j, a, n`

I want to build a regex pattern which searches only strings with ONLY ALL of these characters but it can contains duplicates of these letters. Result of this should looks like:

```
jan
jana
anj
naj
najana
...
```

but shouldn't catch these strings:

```
ana
jaa
nj
aa
nn
a
n
j
..
```

I tried with length-specified strings, etc but for now my closest pattern is following:

`^[jan]{3,}+$`

...where the 3 is count of given characters. But it's still giving me result like `aaa` or `nnn`.

Will be thankful for any help.

Comment: You may use `^(?=[^j]*j)(?=[^a]*a)(?=[^n]*n)[jan]+$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TsvRTg/1).

Comment: That is the same, just adapted so as to work as expected on a *single multiline string* in the demo, with individual strings, it should be `^(?=[^j]*j)(?=[^a]*a)(?=[^n]*n)[jan]+$` and this is why it is in the comment without `\n`s. One should use regex testers carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=.*j)(?=.*a)(?=.*n)[jan]+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/FhQfeR/1